# Issue after migrating from oracle 11g to oracle 12c facing unknown Oracle major version [11]

Tags: hibernate, jboss, oracle12c

After migrating java+spring+hibernate application to oracle 12c , deployed in Jboss EAP  6.1 unknown Oracle major version[12][org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.StandardDialectResolver].

- Using hibernate 4.2.7
- Using OJDBC6
- java 7
- Jboss eap 6.1
- dialect using : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Dialect value is null after migration to oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using higher version of hibernate jar, atleast 4.2.18+ for this. Please have a look at below link to know which version of JDBC to use for various Oracle databases. Also, ensure that there is no other hibernate jars in the JBOSS bundled libraries.

Check for [compatible versions for databases](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix).